# Restricting importing groups while importing users from LDAP into Jira

Tags: ldap, jira

I don't want to import the groups from LDAP into Jira, while importing the users from LDAP in Jira.

I am not familiar to LDAP, but I want to import only users in Jira.

Is there anything that can be done at Jira level to restrict importing groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fill out your directory settings with the correct, but set the 'Group Object Filter" to an LDAP filter that will match nothing, you will not import any groups.

An example of a globally non-matching LDAP filter would be `(1=2)`

If you are using this technique, the other group LDAP settings become redundant, so you can set them as you please.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. On my Configure LDAP User Directory page in jira, under the Group Schema Settings, groupOfUniqueNames is assigned to objectClass in Group Filter . As I said, I am not familiar with LDAP part, can you please tell me how do I tackle this so that the groups in LDAP does not get import in Jira.

Comment: @Naren When you say "groupOfUniqueNames" is assigned to "objectClass" in the filter, does that mean the "Group Object Filter" field contains the text "(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)"?  If so, try changing that to "(1=2)".  HTH!

Comment: Sorry for being late to accept your answer. I want to sync only a specific group from LDAP into a particular **jira-user** group present in Jira. i.e., I want to import an LDAP user from group, say, **ldap-group** into Jira to a group **jira-user**. Is there any workaround

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  I have the same problem in my setup.  Perhaps ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there is a way to tell LDAP not to return the groups (in JIRA or otherwise), but you can tell JIRA not to use the groups to create JIRA groups. In my experience, JIRA will not automatically create JIRA groups to match LDAP groups if you use the setting "Read Only, with Local Groups".

I can't test that right now, I don't have my test server running. But I think that is the way it works. So if that is what you are trying to accomplish, then that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify what you want out of LDAP with extreme precision, certainly including whether you get users, groups, organizations, etc. Look up the LDAP search filter syntax. You will also need to know which LDAP schema is in use at the server, at least for users.